# Abort form post in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

How can I abort a form submission(through JavaScript or JQuery) which post a file to server for upload?

Below is the scenario

1. User browse a file to upload
2. Once the file is selected, the code submits the form
3. Now, a form post is made to the server
4. Is it possible to interrupt or abort the file upload process ?

Please help..

Comment: [abort?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `document.execCommand('Stop')`

This will stop all loading-processes of the document(inclusive pending form-submissions)

Comment: if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
window.document.execCommand('Stop');
}
else
{
window.stop();
}